# Delete local file which is already deleted in repository

Tags: svn

I have a file in my local copy that is not in the repository anymore. Somehow (don't ask me how) it did not got deleted in my local copy.
Anyhow, if I try to delete the file locally, then SVN wants to commit the change, but can't because it is not in the repository anymore ("0 files commited, 1 failed to commit: delete 06.php
svn: E160028: Commit failed (details below)
(translated) /trunk/htdocs/06.php is outdated")

So I can't commit that I deleted the file locally too. The file stays always in my commit list.

I also tried to "SVN cleanup" already. No effect at all.

The biggest problem is that I can't update anymore, because SVN is always throwing the error: "Error: svn: local working copy path htdocs/06.php does not exist in the repository" (translated)

I have no clou how to get rid of this file(s). I am using PHPStorm.

Comment: Do you have uncommitted changes? If not, you could just delete the working copy and check out a new one.

Comment: Yes, I do have uncommited changes. And it would be cool to find a way without deleting the whole working copy.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `svn status`. It will show if there are any conflicts; it might be a [tree conflict](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.treeconflicts.html). Thank you.